# How to filter rows in H2OFrame (scala) based on a column value?

Tags: scala, h2o, sparkling-water

I am reading an `H2OFrame` from a CSV file:

`val h2oFrame = new H2OFrame(new File(inputCsvFilePath))`

How can I perform an equivalent of a `.filter()` operation (as available for Spark `DataFrame` or `RDD`). For example, how do I get a new `H2OFrame` where "label" (which is a column name) is `>1`?

I have tried converting to a `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` as below (simplified example):

```
val df = asDataFrame(h2oFrame)
val dff = df.filter(s"label > 1")
print(dff.toString(0,15))
```

But this seems to throw `OutOfMemoryError` like below:

> Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Executor task launch worker-2"

Comment: Okay, looks like the `OutOfMemoryError` can be solved by increasing `-XX:MaxPermSize=92m` to something higher. Would still like an answer to the original question on how to do it directly on `H2OFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do this the way you are - via Spark. From the [FAQ](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/index.html?_ga=1.104671491.2082339081.1461774427#FAQ-Sparkling%20Water):

> How do I filter an H2OFrame using Sparkling Water?
>
> Filtering columns is easy: just remove the unnecessary columns or
>   create a new > H2OFrame from the columns you want to include
>   (Frame(String[] names, Vec[] vec)), then make the H2OFrame wrapper
>   around it (new H2OFrame(frame)).
>
> Filtering rows is a little bit harder. There are two ways:
>
> Create an additional binary vector holding 1/0 for the in/out sample
>   (make sure to take this additional vector into account in your
>   computations). This solution is quite cheap, since you do not
>   duplicate data - just create a simple vector in a data walk.
>
> or
>
> Create a new frame with the filtered rows. This is a harder task,
>   since you have to copy data. For reference, look at the #deepSlice
>   call on Frame (H2OFrame)